# Adding Twitter API to my app

Tags: java, android, twitter

I want to be able to add a Twitter timeline into my app and also allow the user to update his/her status. The problem is I can't figure out how to get to the login screen. I tried searching online, but all the ones on their are outdated and I want to develop for version 4.0+.

Here is what I have so far: The code doesn't seem to work at all because I used this for an Android app for Android > 4.0, So it will not compile with a SDK of 15 or higher. Also this time I am using the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library and the files have all been updated.

```
package com.shirwa.texthero.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.shirwa.texthero.R;

public class TwitterTab extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    static final String TAG = "MyTwitter";

    TwitterTab twitter;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    Button buttonUpdate;
    Button buttonPrefs;
    EditText textStatus;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View src) {
        String status = textStatus.getText().toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on " + status);

        // Toast
        Toast.makeText(this, textStatus.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // set twitter status
        twitter.updateStatus(status);

        // reset status string
        textStatus.setText("");
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // find views by id
        buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        textStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

        // Add listener
        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initialize twitter
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String username = prefs.getString("username", "n/a");
        String password = prefs.getString("password", "n/a");
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Called when menu item is selected //
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuPrefs:
            // Launch Prefs activity
            Intent i = new Intent(TwitterTab.this, Prefs.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "MenuPrefs starting Prefs");
            Toast.makeText(TwitterTab.this, textStatus.getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't figure out **what**? You have listed code but not the problem itself. Add a little clarity to your question. What doesn't work in the code you have posted.

Comment: I made the edits. Sorry for not being clear to begin with.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't follow. Are you stuck with getting the Login done? Are you stuck posting to Twitter? Are you stuck fetching the timeline? Are you stuck at getting the app to work on lower SDK's? I am absolutely lost.

Comment: I am stuck with the login. If I can. Get past the login, I should be able to fetch the timeline..

Comment: Aah. Now I finally get it. Check my post for more information plus a few bonus goodies. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Before I begin, let me start by saying, I don't typically post link, only answers. I may have done so as a beginner, but hardly any more. Unless the post is a legit and valid one which cannot be answered in it's entirety without links.*

To get started with logging in to Twitter via your app, here is a brilliant little tutorial that should get you started:

[Android Twitter oAuth Connect Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) plus posting a Status Update after having logged in.

You can also take a look at an example hosted on GitHub, [T4JTwitterLogin](https://github.com/ppierson/T4JTwitterLogin). This is another example for logging in to Twitter with your app and posting a Status Update too.

As for the bonus goodies (well, just the one actually). Once you are a little comfortable with Android developed in it's entirety, or perhaps when you can start deciphering other developers code, here is a complete functioning [Android Application for Twitter](https://github.com/chrislacy/TweetLanes) that is open source, available on the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tweetlanes.android) and is fairly popular on it.

This is a link to the search results on GitHub with the keywords Android and twitter4J: https://github.com/search?q=android+twitter4j&type=Repositories&s=updated

Answer (score 1):

I have developed **TWITTER** in my APP.It is working sucessfully..Here is the [LINK](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/)

You can develop for your app.

Answer (score 0):

What API is it that you actually using there?

There is no official twitter SDK built for android, just their REST API. For that purpose, I can personally recommend the library "Scribe" to handle integration with twitter. It can handle authentication, posting and any other function specified in the REST API.

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Comment: You will need the third party library like Scribe that I linked to be able to handle the oauth connection to twitter and use it's REST API.

Comment: Wait, so I would implement this into my main.java or create a separate class for it?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to authenticate your app which will require 2 secretkey (which will be provided to you by twitter during you app registration).

Second, you need to authenticate using Oauth, you can can Google it,(try singly).

Third ,handle the callback and handle the required response.
[use this for reference](http://blog.tarams.com/index.php/2012/twitter-integration-with-android-app-using-oauth/)